# Can Lombok be configured with NetBeans 16?

Tags: java, netbeans, lombok

Does NetBeans 16 support Lombok? Or, do I need to drop down to an early version of NetBeans in order to use it? I have a Maven Spring Boot project (Java 11) that will require Lombok support. So, far, the instructions I've come across for adding Lombok support to NetBeans do not appear to apply to NetBeans 16.

...so far, I've seen

***(1)***

> a. Download the lombok.jar file and save it on your system. 
> b. Right-click the TestAnn project’s node and choose Properties. 
> c. Select the Libraries category in the Project Properties dialog. 
> d. Click Add JAR/Folder in the Compile tab and locate the lombok.jar file that you downloaded

and...

***(2)***

> a. Add lombok.jar to the project libraries. 
> b. In the project properties, in the section Build – Compiling, check the 'Enable Annotation Processing in Editor' checkbox.

Neither of the above instructions appear to apply to what I now see in NetBeans 16 menus or context menus

Does NetBeans 16 IDE support Lombok? If it does, then how is the lombok.jar applied/installed?

Answer (score 0):

If NetBeans 16 is a running version without any bugs it will support the Lombok plugin. In NetBeans IDE use the Lombok Plugin for Maven this way,  just include the dependency in your project POM.xml file and the plugin automatically applies the required configurations. Add the following dependency and check once:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```